# Шифрование - Асимметричное и симметричное

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование, rsa, key

Начал изучать шифрование. Не понятные некоторые вещи.
`Telegram`, `WhatsApp` используют шифрование с открытым ключом. Как одному юзеру удается расшифровать сообщение другого юзера? если закрытый ключ для расшифровки будет только у одного, и получается, что только один сможет расшифровать.. разве не так? Еще читал про `end-to-end`, как я понял, это тот же принцип, то есть "публичный и приватный ключ"... Прошу разъяснить

Comment: Ну да, закрытым ключом только один и может расшифровать. В групповых чатах и каналах телеграма никакого шифрования нет и не будет

Comment: тогда как реализовано шифрование в секретном чате в телеграмм?

Comment: если расшифровать сообщение может только один участник

Comment: Вот только получатель и может расшифровать. Отправитель шифрует сообщение *открытым* ключом получателя, получатель его получает и расшифровывает своим *закрытым* ключом

Comment: это я понял.. а если тот который расшифровал сообщение, захочет написать сообщение? генерируется новая пара ключа? зашифровать можно же только открытым ключом?

Comment: У одного собеседника есть открытый и закрытый ключ, и у другого собеседника тоже есть открытый и закрытый ключ — две пары ключей. При отправке сообщения один собеседник шифрует открытым ключом другого собеседника, в обратную сторону аналогично

Answer (score 0):

Самая примитивная схема:
Есть ты и твой друг.
У тебя есть твой закрытый ключ и открытый ключ друга. 
Ты посылаешь сообщение другу, шифруешь его открытым ключом друга. 
Друг получает сообщение, расшифровывает его своим закрытым ключом. 
Отправляет тебе ответ, шифрует его твоим открытым ключом, ты его получаешь, расшифровываешь своим закрытым.

В реальности всё несколько сложнее, но это целая отдельная тема, которую в один ответ на SO не уместить.

Comment: теперь понятно, получается 2 пары ключей?